# Swift Error when trying to convert int to string

Tags: swift, string, int

When I am trying to convert a string to an int I get an App Delegate Error. It closes my app for IOS and tells me in the command line that I have gotten an Error and gives me info about it. I am using the latest version of Xcode. My GameViewController code:

```
let SpaceShips : Int = 1

@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
@IBAction func NewSpaceShip(sender: AnyObject) {
    SpaceShips + 1

    var stringValue : String?
    stringValue = String(SpaceShips)
    Label1.text = stringValue
```

Where The Error leads me to:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the FAQ, such as http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @David I assume that the error is "signal sigabrt"?

Comment: Yes, It is. Sorry for not putting that up

Comment: `SpaceShips + 1` doesn't assign the value to anything, so it's a no-op.
You probably meant  `var spaceShips : Int = 1` and later `spaceShips += 1`.
Other than that, the only line that can crash is `Label1.text = ...`, since the label might be nil. Are you sure the outlet is connected properly?

Comment: Didn't work but hope this helps because it was on the Dev Command Line: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: What line does it crash on? What are the variables values at the spot it crashed?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: The error is on the class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate but because i am new to Swift and Xcode in general I don't know why that would be a problem.

Comment: You need to step through the code line by line starting when it is still healthy, and see what line actually triggers the abort

Comment: It is the first thread and in the first file read named 0_pthread_kill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, I solved the problem by starting a new project and coping my code into it. The NSException must of been a bug from a answer on a Question named Int to String Swift or something like that. I remember it had a NSException or something with NS.